# How do I pull from Google Analytics and create a trending threads section based on most popular content

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I want to add something like the trending section here:
https://community.logitech.com/s/
(it's on the right side)

I want to place the top ten threads, in descending order, based on which has the most hits on Google Analytics, "unique pageview".

I'm limited to front-end languages (html/css/js). Is there an API or something for this, any suggestions?

Comment: Yes using the GA API.https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference

Comment: Sweet, I was looking for a resource like this. I'll have to dig through it and see what I can find out.

Comment: If you want to save yourself the programming you can do a report in Google Data Studio and embed it in your web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Google Analytics API can do this.

[Google Analytics API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference)

Comment: Thanks, another user mentioned this but never "answered", this did the trick btw ;)

Comment: I noticed, easy answer :P. Thanks for selecting.